# Use getter/setter with HQL query?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I'd like to use an `@Embedded` field directly using a wrapping getter/setter with a `HQL` sql statement.

But it does not work:

```
 org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: address.zip of: Customer [SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.address.zip :=zip]
```

Is the following possible?

```
@Embeddable
pulic class ZipCode {
    String country;
    String zip;
}
@Embeddable
public class Address {
    String street;
    String town;

    @Embedded
    ZipCode zipCode;

    public String getZip() {
        return zipCode().getZip();
    }

    public void setZip(String zip) {
        zipCode.setZip(zip);
    }
}

@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Embedded
    Address address;
}

String FIND_BY_ZIP = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.address.zip :=zip";
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `c.address.zipCode`?

Comment: No, I want to (as written above) access a property directly by getter/setter of the nested `@Embedded`. It's just an example. Of course I could write `c.address.zipCode.zip` but I'm trying to achive this without having to nest `.zipCode.*`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the access type to [AccessType.PROPERTY](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/AccessType.html#PROPERTY)

```
@Embeddable
public class Address {
    String street;
    String town;

    @Embedded
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    ZipCode zipCode;

    public String getZipCode() {
        return zipCode().getZip();
    }

    public void setZipCode(String zip) {
        zipCode.setZip(zip);
    }
}
```

And then it would be possible to do

```
String FIND_BY_ZIP = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.address.zipCode :=zip";
```

By default, the access type of properties is [AccessType.FIELD](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/AccessType.html#FIELD) if you put your mapping annotation in the field (e.g. you have `@Embedded` in your `zipCode`).

In order to to override this default behavior, either you can mark your property explicitly with `AccessType.PROPERTY`, or move your `@Embedded` mapping annotation to the `getZipCode()` method.